# MutationObserver not observing in IE11 after using its disconnect function

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-11

My code is as below:

```
var originalTitle = document.title.split("#")[0]; 
var testtar = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];

    try{
         
        document.attachEvent('onpropertychange', function (evt) {
            console.log('inside attachEvent');
            if(evt.propertyName === 'title' && document.title !== originalTitle) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                   document.title = originalTitle;
                }, 0);
            }
        });  
        
    }
    catch(e){
        function disconnect(){
            observer.disconnect();
            setTimeout(function(){
                observer.observe(testtar, config);
                console.log(observer)
            },1000);
            
        }
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
            testtar.innerHTML = originalTitle;
            disconnect();
         
        });
        var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true,                                       characterDataOldValue: true };
        observer.observe(testtar, config);  
    
    
    };
```

I am trying to check for title change using `MutationObserver`, but once I call `observer.disconnect()` and again call its `observe()` method it doesn't work.
The title changes for the second time but still `testtar.innerHTML` is not set to `originalTitle`. Please help.

Comment: I see something pretty similar in Chrome. What worked for me was to delay the call to disconnect by 100ms using another setTimeout, almost as if you have to give the DOM a chance to catch up.